# Image link in angularjs/iconic mobile application not working

Tags: html, angularjs, image, hyperlink, ionic-framework

I'm trying to get these dumb image links in my mobile app to work, I have 3 different ones.. Email, Phone and Website. All fed dynamically. I got them at least able to do something, but it seems to like try to find it within the application itself.. can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I'm really new to mobile applications, this is my first shot so it's rather different than everything else i've done.

```
<div class="row text-center" style="margin-bottom:20px;">
            <div class="col">
                <a style="display:block;text-decoration:none;" ng-href="tel:{{data.company.phoneNumber}}">
                    <div class="well bluegrad-Box">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone white-Icon"></i>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <a style="display:block;text-decoration:none;" ng-href="mailto:{{data.company.emailAddress}}">
                    <div class="well orangegrad-Box">
                        <i class="ion-email white-Icon2"></i>
                    </div>
                    </a>
```

Thank you!!!!

Comment: how are you setting `data.company.phoneNumber`?

Comment: Its an ajax/api call that brings back a company object containing the phone number.

Comment: can you show the code where you are setting it?